# Python/Pandas - Cannot append all rows into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have this code

```
def expander(input_dataframe, n):
  d = dict(tuple(input_dataframe.groupby(input_dataframe.columns[0])))
  u = input_dataframe['Type'].unique()
  cols = ['Type', 'Variants']
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=range(n))

  for i in range(len(u)):
    df2 = d[u[i]].copy()
    df2["Variants"] = np.nan
    df2
  df3 = input_dataframe.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
  print(df3)
```

When I run the code with :

```
expander(input_dataframe=pd.DataFrame({
    'Type':['iPhone', 'iPhone', 'iPhone', 'iPhone', 'Samsung', 'Samsung', 'Samsung', 'Samsung'],
    'Variants':['12 Mini', '12', '12 Pro', '12 Pro Max', 'S21 FE', 'S21', 'S21+', 'S21 Ultra']
}), n = 4)
```

I was expecting the output to be like this :
[image: expectation]

But instead, what I got was like this :
[image: reality]

How can I solve this?

Comment: You overwrite the `df2` variant for the iPhone with the `df2` variant for the Samsung. If you move your `df3 = input_dataframe.append(df2, ignore_index=True)` into the loop (so just indent it by one indentation), you probably get what you want.

Comment: Note that there is another mistake: you create a base `df2` with the size you want (`n`), but them inside the loop, again, immediately overwrite that because of the `df2 = d[u[i]].copy()` line. It's the same error as stated in my above comment, but plays out differently: the number of appended lines will the amount of existing lines for that type (in both cases, this happens to be 4, just what you set `n` to, so you won't notice it. But change `n=5` in the last line (where you call `exander()` and you'll see how it goes wrong.

Comment: Additional comment: `NaN` for a string type (the Variant column) is a bad idea in my opionion: NaN is a number type (despite its name stating it's not a number). Just `None` or an empty string, `""` for values where you don't know the variant.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the advice :) This is for my assignment and what you mentioned before is a constraint that must exist in the code where it is impossible for n to exceed the original number of lines per group. And I've tried move the ```df3 = input_dataframe.append(df2, ignore_index=True)``` into the loop but it still doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Ah, yes, I overlooked that: make your last line `input_dataframe.append(df2, ignore_index=True)` (and keep it inside the loop). Again the same error: you assign to `df3` twice, but never keep track of the updates. Replacing `df3` with `input_dataframe` will do that.